# embedded programming in c with pointers

Tags: c

When I am try to compile the following program it shows an error in the line LCDCMEMCTL[i] = digit[i]; as this expression must have pointer to object type.Can you please help meto find what is the reason behind it and how to solve this.

```
#include "msp430f6736.h"

char digit[10] = {
    0xB7, /* "0" LCD segments a+b+c+d+e+f */
    0x12, /* "1" */
    0x8F, /* "2" */
    0x1F, /* "3" */
    0x3A, /* "4" */
    0x3D, /* "5" */
    0xBD, /* "6" */
    0x13, /* "7" */
    0xBF, /* "8" */
    0x3F  /* "9" */
};

void main(void)
{
    int i;

    /* Initialize LCD driver (4Mux mode) */
    LCDCCTL0 = 0xFF;

    /* display "6543210" */
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
       LCDCMEMCTL[i] = digit[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a `C` question, not `C#`. They are different languages. You might need to take a look [FAQ] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Please include the error message received after compling.

Comment: The array `LCDCMEMCTL` is probably defined in `msp430f6736.h`, you need to find the definition of it and add it here.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide more input if I’ve found the wrong one... but from what I found in the [msp430f6736.h header file](http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/msp430mcu/ci/master/tree/upstream/msp430f6736.h#l49):

```
#define LCDCMEMCTL_           0x0A06    /* LCD_C memory control register */
sfrb(LCDCMEMCTL_L , LCDCMEMCTL_);
sfrb(LCDCMEMCTL_H , LCDCMEMCTL_+1);
sfrw(LCDCMEMCTL, LCDCMEMCTL_);
```

It looks like `LCDCMEMCTL` is the address of the LCD's memory control register. I haven't found a reference manual for this IC yet, so I don't know what the register looks like. But normally you'd write the full sequence of bytes to the register, a lot of times TI provides macros for writing these.